# Codeigniter Model/Controller functions structure

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have googled this many times and no matter how i worded my google search i don't get results that answers my question. This has been troubling me for months. I also tried looking at sample codeigniter projects to look at how they structured their projects but most of them are not 'full' projects and mostly just parts of a project or confusing.

Let's say i have a profile controller, where all functions for profiling is done.(user and item profile).

profile controller:

```
public function my_user_profile(){
//access profile of logged on user
//needs user authentication
}

public function user_profile(){
//access profile of other users
}

public function item_profile(){
//access profile of item
}
```

Problem occurs when adding access hierarchy to the project since some functions needs a user to be logged in, for example my_user_profile function is accessing your profile thus a user needs to be logged in.

Other functions are public in which they dont need users logged on to be accessed like viewing other people's profile and item profiles(which are public - like in amazon i can view items there even when im not logged on, or in facebook where i can view other people's basic profile without logging in).

Even if i divided it into two controllers named user_controller where all user relevant functions belong and item_controller where all item relevant functions belong.

but still, not all functions needs a user to be logged in so i will have to separate these functions.

This also applies to the models as they reflect my controllers(user_controller will usually call on user_model, item_controller to item_model).

The only thing i can think of is to divide my controllers into two sub-folders namely public and private.(if i add an admin later on, will also make an admin folder)

where public folder with controllers will have functions that don't need user authentication.

and private folder with controllers needs to have a user authentication otherwise redirect to the login page.

possibly an admin folder with controllers that needs an admin account logged in.

Ofcourse the name stays the same, for example:

1. controllers/public/user_profile.php
2. controllers/private/user_profile.php

Is this structuring correct? Is there an accepted standard structuring for projects in codeigniter?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a specific "accepted standard" for CodeIgniter. However, if your suggested structure works for you, use it. These kind of questions are actually off-topic here on SO since it's basically just going to attract opinionated answers. There are almost as many standards out there as there are developers.

Comment: I was hoping there was, I'm trying to be organized and structured not only in my coding but also in structuring my project. Before i could care less but now i wanted to structure everything in a way it only takes a single glance to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have no problem using that kind of structure, just be sure you're calling what you want in routes.php file.

I've a similar structure in controllers and it works:

```
/controllers/controller1.php
/controllers/controller2.php
/controllers/controller3.php
/controllers/logged/controller1.php
/controllers/logged/controller2.php
/controllers/logged/controller3.php
/controllers/admin/controller1.php
/controllers/admin/controller2.php
/controllers/admin/controller3.php
```

Files in controller folder are public, files in logged folder require login and files in admin require a special login. There are some common names, and there is no problem about it, if you set up the routes correctly

Comment: Just a contribution, that folder structure can have only one level of subfolders. There's a documentation here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#organizing-your-controllers-into-sub-directories

Comment: Yes, if you want to recognize more level of subfolders you must set it up in routes.php.